# jquery-ajax post is not working in cross browser

Tags: jquery

```
$.ajax({
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", "AuthenticationToken": "3C9DA1B8-FA69-4195-B1A1-B6CF43CD3ACF" },
    data: "<Employee><GroupId>value</GroupId></Employee>",
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    url: 'https://test.com/Tpx/Employee/testurl/json/v1',

    success: function (data) {
        alert('Success');
    },
    error: function (json, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("jqXHR= " + json.statusText + ", textStatus= " + textStatus + ", errorThrown= " + errorThrown)
    }
```

We are posting data to webservice using ajax method.

But in chrome and IE 10 it is going to error block always. In Firefox it is working fine sometimes and sometimes it  is not working.

We need to post data, send header to service and our service is CORS enabled.

Please help to do stable code to achieve this in cross browser.

Best Regards,
Bala

Comment: sometimes specify `dataType` does a trick

Comment: Are you sure this is not server error?

Comment: jsonp doesn't support sync request nor POST method

Comment: @A.Wolff, OP has issues with cross browser and not cross domain.

Comment: content type is json but the data format is xml ?

Comment: can't you try this `url: '/Tpx/Employee/testurl/json/v1',` try to takeout the `http://....` part from it also try to put a proper `dataType`.

Comment: @AmitJoki i was thinking OP was doing a cross domain request, maybe i'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

AJAX Cross browser doesn't works as per desire.

They are subject to the same origin policy restrictions.

In the ajax settings try adding and check:

```
// the name of the callback parameter, as specified by the service
jsonp: "callback",

// tell jQuery we're expecting JSONP
dataType: "jsonp",
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `dataType:'json'`, like,

```
$.ajax({
    dataType:'json',
    .....
});
```

Read [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax)